# Google Sheet Back End Data Integrity

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet used for employee time entry on Sheet1 that collects data into a second back end "Data" sheet which uses a lot of VLOOKUP functions based on other sheets. There have been some issues with people cutting and pasting or dragging cell/row positions which causes REF errors and also throws off the VLOOKUP formulas on the Data sheet. I am not sure VLOOKUP is the way to go with this as badly as the references can get borked. If anyone can suggest a better way of getting the data in the data sheet feel free to let me know.
Sheet is shared here and pretty well sanitized.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W7YFNkKC-Ruelvls_kJKsnuxYkJn8O5WuZmhKhUhbh4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OFFSET` function in which you can set it to only reference the header rows.  The header rows usually do not get cut and pasted else where making it a fairly stable reference.

`OFFSET` **In Action:**

In your `Data` sheet in cell `C2` you can use this formula instead.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,ROW()-1,0),Employees!A$2:B$100,2,false),"")
```

If you take this approach for the other formulas you should be able to get to a more stable file.

EDIT: I also wanted to mention if others are using this file you can protect the header range making it impossible to mess up the formulas.

Comment: THat did the job. I will have to roll how OFFSET works in my brain in this context, but it seems to work the way I envisioned. Cut and paste may still be an issue on Sheet1

Comment: @Rockn For sure, just leave a comment if you run into cut and paste issues and we can work it out.

Comment: I had to do some slight modification to Sheet1 and the way the Phase Codes are collected in the Data sheet using SPLIT. Can I still use OFFSET if not VLOOKUP. If you look at the formula on the data sheet for the phase codes you will see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble understanding your issue here.  What is it you are trying to populate in the data sheet for the phase column?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the issue and it wouldn't let me update my earlier posting. Thanks for the help.